# Euclidean domains and Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I've been wrtiting a chain of inclusions of algebraic structures as given at the end of this first paragraph on wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain

And I've been giving examples of an algebraic structure that seperates each link in the chain (e.g. a ring that is not a commutative ring) and I'm at the final hurdle!

I'm having trouble though, with understanding what exactly a Euclidean domain is? I like things explained in words a lot of the time though I appreciate that is difficult sometimes.

I also am having to give an example of a Euclidean domain that is not a field! This is essentially my question (what is an example?).

I understand the criteria for a field is:

A commutative ring, with the added property of having a multiplicative inverse.

Any help is greatly appreciated, so thanks

Doug

Comment: A Euclidean domain is a ring that "behaves like the integers" in that there is a way of performing Euclids algorithm. An example of an Euclidian domain that is not a field is the integers themselves!

Comment: First thing you need to do is stop reading Wikipedia. It is a minefield of disinformation. Read this instead: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ringtheory/euclideanrk.pdf

Comment: Second, I suggest getting familiar with Euclid's algorithm for the GCD and trying it out with a few pairs of numbers in $\mathbb{Z}$, like $-48$ and 50.

Comment: @robertsoupe I don't agree with that assessment. The mathematics pages are usually very reliable. Wikiproject math and its contributes jump on mistakes and poor writing. Of course there is no substitute for the caution that everyone must exercise while reading Wikipedia.

Comment: @rschwieb Not every gun is loaded, and yet our Marines are trained to treat every weapon as if it were. So I suggest to treat every Wikipedia article as if it were completely false. And even when Wikipedia articles are correct, they're not always clear. This article from 2013 has some examples that are probably still valid today: http://wikipediocracy.com/2013/10/20/elementary-mathematics-on-wikipedia-2/

Comment: Dear @RobertSoupe : sure I agree with "treat it as if it were loaded" since that's exactly my last sentence in my last comment. To follow this analogy with your recommendation, your marine commander would order his charges to *stop using guns*. I just had to intercede to push back against the misrepresentation of wikipedia. I don't intend to push anymore on this thread. Regards

Comment: Dear @RSchwieb So my analogy is not entirely apt (I was never in the Marine Corps, so no one accuse me of stolen valor please). Last night on the Wikipediocracy forum, Michael D. Suarez posted the following proposed slogan for Wikipedia: "Wikipedia: Where the Founder appoints fake Doctors of Theology to ArbCom, and where ArbCom crushes genuine professors in mathematics."

Comment: To get back on topic, Doug, do you understand what the Euclidean GCD algorithm is and how it applies to ordinary integers?

Comment: I believe I do @RobertSoupe - Am I right in think it's when you draw a line seperating the two numbers and you call them a and b (not necessarily) and then you see how many times a fits in to be, and subtract the difference.... etc... Hard to explain, but you'll know if I'm thinking of the right thing. If it isn't that then I'm afraid I don't know!

Comment: @Doug So for example, to compute $\gcd(-128, 70)$ (you already know the answer is 2, but please play along) what would be your next step?

Answer (score 0):

*getting this out of unanswered-limbo*

---

> I also am having to give an example of a Euclidean domain that is not a field! This is essentially my question (what is an example?).

As mentioned in the comments, one can say a Euclidean domain is a domain "that has a division algorithm like the integers."

This is formalized by requiring the existence of a function $v:R\setminus\{0\}\to \mathbb N$ such that for every $a$ and nonzero $b$ there exists $q$ and $r$ such that $a=bq+r$ and either $r=0$ or $v(r)<v(b)$.

When we say "like the integers" we really mean it: $\mathbb Z$ is a Euclidean domain, and $v(x)=|x|$ can be used as the function.

Another example is the ring of polynomials $F[x]$ where $F$ is a field, because we can use $v(f)=\deg f$.

Neither of these are fields.